# MySQL where clause targeting dependent subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-attribute-value

I work with entity-attribute-value database model.

My product have many attribute_varchars and attribute_varchars have one attribute. An attribute has many attribute_varchars and an attribute varchar has one product. Same logic apply to attribute_decimals and attribute_texts.

Anyway, i have the following query and i would like to filter the result using a where clause

```
SELECT 
    products.id,
    (select value from attribute_texts    where product_id = products.id and attribute_id = 1) 
        as description,
    (select value from attribute_varchars where product_id = products.id and attribute_id = 2) 
        as model,
    (select value from attribute_decimals where product_id = products.id and attribute_id = 9) 
        as rate,
    (select value from attribute_varchars where product_id = products.id and attribute_id = 20) 
        as batch
FROM products
WHERE products.status_id <> 5
```

**I would like to add a where `rate > 5`**

I tried but I get the following error : `Unknown column 'rate' in 'where clause'`. I tried adding an alias to the value and to the table of the value but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do:

```
having rate > 5
```

MySQL has extended the `having` clause so it can work without a `group by`.  Although questionable as a feature, it does allow you to reference aliases in the `select` clause without using a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

With generated column like that, the best way is to made your query as a subquery, and do your filtering on the upper level like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT 
    products.id,
    (select value from attribute_texts    where product_id = products.id and attribute_id = 1) 
        as description,
    (select value from attribute_varchars where product_id = products.id and attribute_id = 2) 
        as model,
    (select value from attribute_decimals where product_id = products.id and attribute_id = 9) 
        as rate,
    (select value from attribute_varchars where product_id = products.id and attribute_id = 20) 
        as batch

FROM products
WHERE products.status_id <> 5
) as sub
WHERE sub.Rate > 5
```

Comment: It does work but it is significantly less performant than the having clause (as suggested by Gordon's answer). [3.4314 sec vs 0.1874 sec] with a product table of 35k lines, attribute_decimals tables of 130k lines

Answer (score 0):

Use join clauses rather than subqueries for the attribute tables:

```
SELECT 
    p.id,
    a_description.value AS description,
    a_model.value       AS model,
    a_rate.value        AS rate,
    a_batch.value       AS batch
FROM products p
INNER JOIN attribute_texts a_description 
    ON  a_description.product_id = p.id
    AND a_description.attribute_id = 1
INNER JOIN attribute_varchars a_model 
    ON  a_model.product_id = p.id
    AND a_model.attribute_id = 2
INNER JOIN attribute_decimals a_rate 
    ON  a_rate.product_id = p.id
    AND a_rate.attribute_id = 9
INNER JOIN attribute_varchars a_batch
    ON  a_batch.product_id = p.id
    AND a_batch.attribute_id = 20
WHERE products.status_id <> 5
  AND a_rate.value > 5
```

Comment: I don't use the inner join because the sub-querys are much more performant in my situation.